# How to generate generic method using java poet?

Tags: java, javapoet

I want generate below code using **[javapoet](https://github.com/square/javapoet)**

*Javapoet is a library to autogenerate java code.*

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> T[] returnArrayForType(T value) {
    Object array = Array.newInstance(value.getClass(), 1);
    Array.set(array, 0, value);
    return (T[]) array;
}
```

I know how to write for defined types, but how should i deal with it? Can anyone help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a generic array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TypeVariableName`. Below snippet should get you started.

```
TypeVariableName typeVariable = TypeVariableName.get("T");
MethodSpec.Builder methodBuilder = MethodSpec.methodBuilder("returnArrayForType")
        .addParameter(typeVariable, "value")
        .addTypeVariable(typeVariable)
        .returns(ArrayTypeName.of(typeVariable))
        .addModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC, Modifier.STATIC);
```

Comment: What about Class<T> as method's parameter?